# javascript and css style sheets not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make the Javascript input text look like the HTML?  Style sheet is not being applied to the Javascript but works fine for HTML.

https://raw.github.com/blackberry/jQueryMobile-BB10-Theme/master/kitchenSink/lib/BlackBerry-JQM-all.css

https://raw.github.com/blackberry/jQueryMobile-BB10-Theme/master/kitchenSink/lib/BlackBerry-JQM-all.js

http://jsfiddle.net/zaDN2/

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/BlackBerry-JQM-all.css" />
    <script src="lib/BlackBerry-JQM-all.js"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="onPageLoad()">
    <div data-role="content" id=content></div><!-- /content -->
    <input type=text id=tPlay2 placeholder=Play_HTML>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setContent(id, msg)
        {
            var ele = document.getElementById(id);
            if (ele) {
                ele.innerHTML = msg;
            }
        }
        function onPageLoad()
        {
            var sPlay;

            sPlay = '<input type=text id=tPlay1 placeholder=Play_JS>';

            setContent("content", sPlay);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating this problem?

Comment: done, the style sheets aren't loading properly with jsFiddle, it works fine in Chrome / BB 10 browser

Comment: The stylesheet isn't loaded because the mime-type is wrong on the file.  The mime-type is text/plain instead of text/css in the fiddle.

Comment: Or it could be that the CSS isn't loaded because it's requested over HTTPS while the jsFiddle page itself is HTTP.

Comment: sorry for the inconvince, *chuckle* I am spending more time trying to get this working in fiddle, if you create a .html page it works fine (well the problem shows up properly)

Comment: fixed the fiddle site with proper CSS, resize not working though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search on you stylesheet for a css class that applies to the inputs that are of type text

for example you might have:

```
input[type='text']
{
    background:red;
}
```

Change it into:

```
input[type='text'], .jsinput
{
    background:red;
}
```

and then change the line of your script into

```
 sPlay = '<input class="jsinput" type=text id=tPlay1 placeholder=Play_JS>';
```

My answer would be more precise if you posted your stylesheet, too.

Comment: Well he generates that input using JS as I understood from his code so maybe if you apply the css class directly it will work

Comment: no, you didnt understand, that property (red background) would apply to all inputs type text and to that single control that he generated using js (the one that will have .jsinput class)

Comment: In that case there is still a bug in your css. Add a comma between the two selectors.

Comment: I think this is the solution, just looking for the silver bullet to make it all work together!

Comment: got it, found the answer in the CSS (bit of a noob with this) class=ui-input-text - many thanks folks!